# Is there polling to suggest that a majority of United Kingdom citizens would favour a codified constitution?

Tags: united-kingdom, constitution, public-opinion

I'm wondering if there is any recent (say within the last decade) polling which would suggest that citizens of the United Kingdom hold a strong opinion one way or another on the subject of a codified constitution for the United Kingdom.

I'm particularly interested in polls which would indicate an opinion either way absent other changes to the structure/constitutional convention of the United Kingdom (in essence a replacement of the UK's "Constitutional Convention" with a written and binding document containing, broadly, the same rights/procedures, subject to obvious changes to the powers of parliament).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The select committee on political and constitutional reform wrote a report on the [arguments for and against a written constituion](https://www.publications.parliament.uk/pa/cm201415/cmselect/cmpolcon/463/46308.htm)

Therein they say:

> Opinion polls show clear popular support for a written constitution, especially when asked about the desirability of setting down clear legal rules within which government ministers and civil servants are forced to act.

But also note

> There is in reality no popular demand for a written constitution. Though opinion polls might appear to show majority backing for it when asked in public attitude surveys, there is minimal depth of feeling or support behind it, as well as little understanding of what it would entail. For the overwhelming majority of people, even among those who like the idea of a written constitution, it is a very low priority for government action in comparison to other matters.

In context, people tend to distrust politicians. So a set of rules that is seen to restrict how politicians can act is generally popular. However people tend not to give the matter much thought, and it is not considered to be important. So *no* polls do not show *strong* opinions one way or the other. They tend to show *weak" support for a written constitution.

Comment: An excellent answer.